# Can a SATA 2.5" disk with a smart error work as removable disk?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart

I have a hard disk that reports a smart error when I try to use it as the installation disk for w10, but when i plug it as an external device it seems to work fine. Can I use it as removable disk ?

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't mind losing data stored on it at some point.

Comment: It will still have the same problem....

Comment: Actually it doesn't **work fine**.  The USB translator is preventing the OS from seeing the problem, but your disk is still on deaths door.